# I want to display column data in Yii2 listview

Tags: yii2

I've try to display my table columns data in listview but it's not working. In gridview it's allow to insert fields name. can't i do it in listview ?

I try this code.

```
$feedbackFound = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql'=> "SELECT * FROM feedback WHERE module_id='$tutorModule->id'",
]);

ListView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $feedbackFound,
                    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                    'itemView' => [
                        'PositiveComment',
                        'GoodAt',
                        'MakeMost',

                        //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
                    ],
            ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView doesn't have the fancy handling that gridview does - it takes data and passes it to a view, giving you some convenience items (pagination, sorting, filtering, etc).

The presentation and use of the convenience items is up to you. `itemView` is not analogous to the `columns` key for gridview.  It's supposed to be a partial view (i.e. a php file you've created or a callback), so you need to define that partial view.  That gives you a lot of flexibility in how each item from your data model is shown, but it requires some work.

Comment: Hi ernie, i just want to display data from my table called 'feedback'. it has 6 fields. fields should be display top to bottom not left to right like Gridview

Comment: Then you should ask that question (in a new post), not a question about how to use ListView, otherwise you're engaging in the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, sim`s answer doesn't work for me, that is why I have changed it a little:

```
$colsCount = 4;
echo ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $itemDataProvider,
    'layout' => '{items}{pager}',
    'options' => ['class' => 'TOP_CLASS_HERE'],
    'itemOptions'  => ['class' => "ITEM_CLASS_HERE"],
    'beforeItem' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) use ($colsCount) {
        if ($index % $colsCount === 0) {
            return "<div class='row'>";
        }
    },
    'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
        return $this->render('@frontend/views/item/_card.php', ['item' => $model]);
    },
    'afterItem' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) use ($colsCount) {
        $content = '';
        if (($index > 0) && ($index % $colsCount === $colsCount - 1)) {
            $content .= "</div>";
        }
        return $content;
    },
]);
if ($itemDataProvider->count % $colsCount !== 0) {
    echo "</div>";
}
```

I tested it on big amount of data and it works perfect. I like this solution, hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this code, it displays items from left to right, from top to bottom in a three columns. This code uses the following bootstrap css classes: `col-sm-?` and `row` to make a proper grid.

```
$columns = 3;
$cl = 12 / $columns;

echo ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'layout'       => '{items}{pager}',
        'itemOptions'  => ['class' => "col-sm-$cl"],
        'itemView'     => '_view_list_item',
        'options'      => ['class' => 'grid-list-view' ],
        'beforeItem'   => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) use ($columns) {
            if ( $index % $columns == 0 ) {
                return "<div class='row'>";
            }
        },

        'afterItem' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) use ($columns) {
            if ( $index != 0 && $index % ($columns - 1) == 0 ) {
                return "</div>";
            }
        }
]);

if ( $dataProvider->totalCount % $columns != 0 ) {
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: it does not work after first column. You need to change afterItem as @GHopper did and it works fine

Comment: `'afterItem' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) use ($columns) {
            if ( $index > 0 && ($index % $columns == $columns -1 )) {
                return "</div>";
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

This variant don't work with \yii\bootstrap\Tabs and pagination, because code always insert div:

```
//if ( $dataProvider->totalCount % $columns != 0 ) {
//    echo "</div>";
//}
```

This variant work with \yii\bootstrap\Tabs and pagination:

```
if ( $dataProvider->totalCount % $columns != 0 ) {
    if ($dataProvider->pagination->pageCount-1 == $dataProvider->pagination->page) {
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the commented code part of the solution?

Comment: Also give a bit of explanation what you did and why it works.